# .net core 2.2 app returns "This site can’t be reached" when run on IIS version 10

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I have recently downloaded a copy of nopCommerce and installed it. Pressing F5 in visual studio, it ran successfully on IIS Express. I have now enabled IIS and would like to run this site on IIS but when I click "browse" in IIS I get the message "This site can’t be reached". I am running VS in admin mode and enabled `development-time IIS support` but I still haven't got it working.

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://nopCommerce.local.com",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Nop.Web": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://nopCommerce.local.com:443/"
    },
    "IIS": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://nopCommerce.local.com:443/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "nativeDebugging": true
    }
  }
}
```

**IIS Application Pool**

`.Net Clr version: No Managed code`

`Managed pipeline mode: integrated`

**IIS Site Bindings**

`Type: https`

`IP address: all unassigned`

`Port: 443`

`Host Name: nopCommerce.local.com`

`Required server name indication: false`

`Disable HTTP2: false`

`Disable OCSP stapling: false`

`SSL certificate: IIS Express Development Certificate`

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run a report and the typical issues can be identified.

Comment: Do you mean you want directly run your .net core application in visual studio with IIS instead of IIS express?

Comment: As you appear to run this locally, on a _localhost_, and if, you also need to assign that domain to IIS `hosts` file, e.g. `127.0.0.1   nopCommerce.local.com`, or else it will go online to look for it.